Showing that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ assuming basic linear algebra and min amount of abs alg.
The following are from Froberg's Introduction to Grobner bases, and Hungerford's undergraduate Abstract Algebra text.
Background
Theorem 1: $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n]\backsimeq (k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}])[x_n]$
Theorem 2:  Let $K$ be an extension field of $F$ and $u\in K$ an algeebraic element over $F$ with minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$.  Then
$(1)$ $F(u)\equiv F(x)/(p(x))$
$(2)$ $\{1_F,u,u^2,\ldots,u^{n-1}\}$ is a basis of the vector space $F(u)$ over $F$.
$(3)$ $[F(u):F]=n$.
Exercise: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal generated by monomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  Show that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ if and only if for each $i$ there is a $d_i>0$, such that ${x_i^{d_i}}\in \mathfrak{a}$.
Questions
I am trying to do the Exercsie above.  The book I am used at the point where the exercsie is introduced has not discussed any notions of affine algebraic sets or algebraic varieties.  IT only assume the reader has a knowledge of linear algebra and calculus.  I am trying to do the question with the addition of a basic course of abstract algebra with the assumed facts of Theorem 1, 2  quoted above.  I know that other introductory texts like Cox O'Shea and LIttle's text, the above Exercsie would be proved inchapter 5 section 3 of their text.  By that point of the text, terminology from Grobner bases would have been hesvily introduced. I am trying to do the exercise without resorting to learning anything Grobner bases first.  Hence can someone please comment on my proof below if what I have done below is correct.
Attempted solution:  To show that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a vector space, and from Thoerem 1, it amounts to showing that $(k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}])[x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a vector space which can be done by showing that $(k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}])[x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a quotient vector space.  What remains to be shown is that it is finite dimensional.  So  assume that $x_i^{d_i}\in \mathfrak{a}$, and suppose $x_i^{d_i}+\langle \mathfrak{a}\rangle \in (k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}])[x_i]/\mathfrak{a}$.  Letting $F= (k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]), u=x_i, F(u)=(k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}])[x_i], p(x)=\sum_{i_1i_2\cdots i_n}a_{i_1i_2\cdots i_n}x_1^{d_1}x_2^{d_2}\cdots x_{i-1}^{d_{i-1}} x_{i+1}^{d_{i+1}}\cdots x_{n}^{d_{n}})x_i^{d_i}$ in the hypothesis of Theorem 2, then by $(2)$ of that theorem, $\{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]},x_i,x_i^2,\ldots,x_i^{{d_i}-1}\}$ is a basis of the vector space $(k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}])[x_i]$ over $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]$.  There are $n$ indeterminates in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n]$ and by Theorem 1, for each $x_i$ that is allow to varied, there are $d_i$ number of basis elements, hence, and there are $n$ indeterminates that can be varied while for each indeterminate held varied, the remaining $n-1$ indeterminates are considered to be part of the coefficents of an $n$ variable polynomials.  Hence the dimension of the vector space (not sure if it can also be considered as a quotient vector space, Hungerford and many abstract algebra text don't seem to mention this fact.) $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ must be finite.
Conversely, assume that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a finite dimesional vector space.  Any monomial $x_1^{d_1}\cdots x_n^{d_n}$ can be constructed from elements of the set $\{x_1^{d_1},\ldots x_n^{d_n}\}$.  Hence it is enough to just consider $x_i^v+\mathfrak{a}$, $v=1,2,\dots d_i-1$  is an element of the basis $\{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]},x_i,x_i^2,\ldots,x_i^{{d_i}-1}\}$.  But $x_i^{d_i-1}+\mathfrak{a}=0+\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}$, implying $ x_i\cdot x_i^{d_i-1}=x_i^{d_i}\in\mathfrak{a}$.
Thank you in advance

@KaleBhodre I think so.  To be honest, I am trying to reduce it to the casse of $(2)$ of Theorem 2 if that is possible?  I mean $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$, so it has to be generated by polynomials as an ideal.  I am probably unintentionally have skipped some or a lot of details since at the point where thhis question is asked in the text assumes the reader to have very little knowledge of abstract algebra.

@KaleBhodre Am I allow as you say to assume that $\mathfrak{a}=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$, also, does my proof look okay or have I missed anything that I need to added.  I am trying to keep the proof as simple as possible, meaning, assuming only linear algebra and very little of abstract algebra.  Also how does $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}\cong k$ help with solving the exercsie?

You have the right idea, but you are overcomplicating things. You don't need Thm 2, for example.
Assume that for each $i$, there is some $i$ for which $x^d_i\in\mathfrak{a}$. Then, for all $m_i\geq d_i$, we have $x_i^{m_i}=x^{m_i-d_i} x_i^{d_i}\in\mathfrak{a}$.
In particular, take a monomial $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}$. If there exists at least one $i$ such that $m_i\geq d_i$, then $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}\in\mathfrak{a}$.
Now, an element of the quotient has the form $P=\sum_{m_1,\ldots,m_n\geq 0}a_{m_1,\ldots,m_n} x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}+\mathfrak{a}.$
As you notice, for all $Q\in \mathfrak{a}$, we have $P+Q+\mathfrak{a}=P+\mathfrak{a}.$
The previous point then shows that  $P=\sum_{m_1\leq d_1-1,\ldots,m_n\leq d_n-1}a_{m_1,\ldots,m_n} x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}+\mathfrak{a}.$
Hence, the classes $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}, m_i\leq d_i-1$ for all $i$, span the vector space $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$. Since this family is finite, it follows that this vector space is finite dimensional (of dimension $\leq d_1\cdots d_n$).
Note that we didn't use the fact that $\mathfrak{a}$ is generated by monomials here.
Now for the other direction. Assume to the contrary that there is an $i$ such that $x_i^m\notin \mathfrak{a}$ for all $m>0$; say $i=1$.
We are going to show that the classes $x_1^m+\mathfrak{a},m\geq 0$ are linearly independent, showing our quotient space has infinite dimension.
So assume that $\sum_m \lambda_m x_1^m+\mathfrak{a}=0+\mathfrak{a}$, meaning that $\sum_m \lambda_m x_1^m\in\mathfrak{a}.$ (the $\lambda_m$'s are all zero except from a finite number of them).
By assumption on $\mathfrak{a}$, there are some polynomials $P_1,\ldots,P_r\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and monomials $M_1,\ldots,M_r\in\mathfrak{a}$ such that
$\sum_m \lambda_m x_1^m=P_1M_1+\cdots+P_rM_r$. By assumption, $M_i$ is not a power of $x_1$, so it must contains another variable (we use the fact that $M_i$ is a monomial here).In particular $M_i(x_1, 0,\ldots,0)=0$ for all $i$.
Evaluating the previous equality shows that $\sum_m \lambda_m x_1^m=0\in k[x_1]$, hence $\lambda_m=0$ for all $m$ , as required.

I have a few minor questions.  In your proof, in the statement:  "In particular, take a monomial $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}$. If there exists at least one $i$ such that $m_i\geq d_i$, then $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}$."  I don't understand what you meant by the conclusion then $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}$.".  Is $x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}$ suppose to be an element of $\mathfrak{a}$?  If I don't need Theorem 2, do I still need Theorem 1?  Also, is $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ consider as a quotient vector space?

First question: yes, i meant $"x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}\in \mathfrak{a}$, i've edited . You don't need Thm 1 either. For the third question, yes, what else could it be  ? (the external law is simply $\lambda\cdot(P+\mathfrak{a})=\lambda P+\mathfrak{a}$ )

ah kk.  Thank you so very much.  Can I trouble you with a related post.  It is a sequel to this exercise question about counting bases elements for the dimension of ${\text{dim}}_k k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ but is in the form of a two sided inequaliy.  I think i managed to do one side of the inequality, but not the other.  Thank you in advance.

The RHS is already contained in my answer. For LHS, i have to think about it.

is what I wrote for the LHS in my other post correct?
